# Why does GPG decryption with subkeys fail on one computer but not another?

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg, password-management

I have been attempting to create a system of GPG subkeys to distribute to my various computers. I have created subkey pairs for each computer with the master secret key removed as per the instructions [here](https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2013/12/02/creating-a-new-gpg-key-with-subkeys/) and [here](https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair/). I have the distributed the relevant .gnupg folders to my computers via scp. I am then testing these by attempting to access my pass database. The keypair folder I sent to my laptop works fine and decrypts my passwords, but the one I sent to another headless system does not, and when I attempt to show a password I get the follwoing error message:

> gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

If I try using the same subkey pair .gnupg folder -  the one intended for the headless box -  on my laptop, it works fine to decrypt.

All systems run Arch Linux and the same versions of gnupg 2.1.8 and pass 1.6.5.

Can anyone suggest why the subkeys don't work to decrypt on my headless system?

Comment: Have you copied the `.gnupg` folder to the right user's home directory (the user trying to access the keys) and adjusted the access permissions (user IDs might be different, although user names are similar)? Is showing `gpg --version` the same directory as homedirectory you transferred?

Comment: Yes, `gpg --version` shows the correct directory. I've tried changing the permissions. Can you confirm what they should be? I've used `chown -R stephanie:users .gnupg` to change to the correct owner and used `chown -R 755 .gnupg` to change the permissions, but I still get the same error.

Comment: What is `gpg --list-secret-keys` printing?

Comment: It seems to show what I'd expect: `sec#  rsa4096/0xFAEA411332F636B9 2015-10-12
uid                   [ultimate] Stephanie Anderson <stephanie.anderson.1873@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa4096/0x1C674CBC250C2765 2015-10-12
ssb   rsa4096/0x72D1B3B02E4F1015 2015-10-12`

Comment: I never used `pass`, so I cannot give you the complete route to get more details. Try to find the OpenPGP encrypted contents, and pipe them into `gpg --list-packets`, which should give you more details on which key it is expecting. You might also be able to somehow sneak a `-v` into the GnuPG call, which might add some helpful information on the key it's trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the use of pass was a red herring. I tried simply encrypting a document and then attempting to decrypt it. With the -v flag this showed that the problem was with the pinentry agent. So with the instructions from the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/520980/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-console-mode-pinentry-to-prompt-for-passwords). I have now got it working with pinentry-curses.