# GPG2 Asks for password even with --passphrase specified

Tags: linux, command-line, encryption, passwords

I'm trying to script a gpg decryption, and as such need to provide the password on the command line. According to the man page, there are three ways to do this: read from a file using `--passphrase-file`, read from stdin (or another file descriptor) using `--passphrase-fd 0`, or include in the command line using just `--passphrase`. All of the above also require `--batch` to be set, which I did.

My most recent command line attempt is:

```
echo "<password>" | gpg2 --no-tty --batch --passphrase-fd 0 -d -o /<path_to_destination>/$FILE_NAME $FILE
```

which still pops up a dialog asking for the password. What am I missing here? For reference, if it makes a difference, my password does include some special characters like `&`, but it doesn't appear to complain about that. Also, gpg version is 2.1.9:

```
# gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.9
libgcrypt 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

EDIT: Unlike [How to force GPG to use console-mode pinentry to prompt for passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/520980/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-console-mode-pinentry-to-prompt-for-passwords), which is simply trying to get a text-based password entry for use in a SSH session, I'm trying to get a completely non-interactive method of using GPG for use in scripting.

Comment: gpg version 1.x doesn't have that problem, it actually listens to & honors the `--no-use-agent` flag

Comment: @Xen2050: Not sure how that question is in any way similar. It's asking about getting a text-based prompt to enter the password when using GPG in a SSH session (console-mode pinentry). I looking for how to not be asked for a "pinentry" *at all*, for scripting purposes.

Comment: @Xen2050: Turns out that the question did at least give me some additional search paths (specifically, pinentry), which led to the solution, so thanks!

Comment: When I tried similar scripting I saw the same problem, even with `--passphrase` options it was ignoring it and popping up the gui agent, suppressing the agent made the passphrase options all work. Looked like the same answer should've worked, must be too different with the newer version of gpg. Especially since the answer's different, I guess it's not really a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase

In a nutshell, I needed to first enable the pinentry "loopback" mode in the gpg-agent by adding the following line to the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

Then adding the `--pinentry-mode loopback` argument to my `gpg2` call