# gpg2 --quick-addkey without password prompt

Tags: bash, shell, passwords, gnupg, cryptography

I am trying generate in bash sub keys for a keyring without any keyboard interaction.
I have tried several approach around what is mentioned here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase

The following command ask for password but does generates the sub key even if no password is entered with cancel button:

```
gpg2 --passphrase-file <(echo $pass_poem) --batch --quick-addkey $keyring_hash_id rsa1024 sign 1y
```

Same behavior with this one:

```
echo $pass_poem | gpg2 --batch --no-tty --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --quick-addkey $keyring_hash_id rsa1024 sign 1y
```

I use Ubuntu with and gpg 2.1.15 with libgcrypt 1.7.2-beta

Anyone understands why such a behavior?

Many thx

Comment: You can blame me if you receive any downvotes on this (previously posted on StackOverflow - upvoted and welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution close from

[GPG2 Asks for password even with --passphrase specified](https://superuser.com/questions/1190921/gpg2-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase-specified?rq=1)

Explanation can be found here:

[https://wiki.archlinux.org/....](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase)

adding the following line to the ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file made it:

```
pinentry-mode loopback
```

But this is not recommended as it may break other usage.

Here is a solution:

```
echo $pass_poem | gpg2 --pinentry-mode loopback --batch --no-tty --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --quick-addkey $keyring_hash_id rsa1024 sign 1y
```