# Decrypting file attempts to use sub-key and then gives 'No secret key' error

Tags: gpg-agent

Using:
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
libgcrypt 1.5.3

I am trying to decrypt a file from a remote site. I exported our key to a file. `gpg <filename>` returns: (Key IDs changed)

```
pub 2048R/656CC421 2018-04-19
sub 2048R/99F89J32 2018-04-19
```

I sent it to the sender and asked them to import, sign and trust it.

They sent me two different key files. Using `gpg <filename>` returns:

```
1. pub 2048R/62568LK1 2015-09-03

2. pub 2048R/J561VE25 2015-09-23
```

If I do an edit-key, I get the following:

My key:

```
Secret key is available.

pub 2048R/656CC421 created: 2018-04-19 expires: never usage: SC
trust: ultimate validity: ultimate
sub 2048R/99F89J32 created: 2018-04-19 expires: never usage: E
[ultimate] (1).
```

Their keys:

```
1. pub 2048R/62568LK1 created: 2015-09-23 expires: never usage: SCE
trust: full validity: full
[ full ] (1).

2. pub 2048R/99F89J32 created: 2015-09-03 expires: never usage: SC
trust: full validity: full
[ full ] (1).
```

I am running the decrypt command in a bash script with the following parameters.

```
echo $passphrase | /usr/bin/gpg --verbose --passphrase-fd 0 --no-tty --output $output_file --recipient myuser --decrypt $input_file
```

Following is the output of the command:

```
Version: GnuPG v1.2.4 (MingW32)
gpg: armor header:
gpg: public key is 99F89J32
gpg: using subkey 99F89J32 instead of primary key 656CC421
gpg: using subkey 99F89J32 instead of primary key 656CC421
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 99F89J32, created 2018-04-19
"usrname (Description) <usrname@domain.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

My conclusion from all of this is that the sender needs to send me their public key in the same format that I sent to them. Such as:

```
pub 2048R/J561VE25 2015-09-23
```

*`sub 2048R/SOM3NUMB 2015-09-23`*

My thought it that the key files they sent me don't have the corresponding pub/sub info and therefore gpg can't validate because I only have one part of their keypair's information.

Can anyone tell me if I'm wrong in this or if my thoughts are correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue! Deleted subkey now it can't find secret key to decrypt. More info on that thing is here : https://superuser.com/questions/520980/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-console-mode-pinentry-to-prompt-for-passwords That file is located here `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321712/gpg-decryption-fails-with-no-secret-key-error

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/solve-gpg-decryption-failed-no-secret-key-error/

Comment: This was my cure in the end, just re-import the public key - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262703/deleted-a-subkey-and-can-now-no-longer-decrypt/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Version: GnuPG v1.2.4 (MingW32)
> ```

<del>Holy balls</del> that's old – version 1.2.4 was released in **2003**. The sender doesn't care much about updating their security software, it seems.

(Your own 2.0.22 isn't much better, with 2013 as the release date.)

> ```
> gpg: public key is 99F89J32
> gpg: using subkey 99F89J32 instead of primary key 656CC421
> gpg: using subkey 99F89J32 instead of primary key 656CC421
> ```

That's normal. The "main" keypair is only used for signing (aka certifying) other keys; often also for signing messages. It is not usable for encryption – you always have a subkey for that purpose.

(The separation also allows for such things as offline signing or frequent encryption key rotation.)

> ```
> gpg: cancelled by user
> gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 99F89J32, created 2018-04-19 "usrname (Description) <usrname@domain.com>"
> gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelled
> gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
> ```

Sounds like GnuPG tried to display a passphrase prompt to unlock *your* keypair, but either the passphrase window failed to open, or you accidentally cancelled it yourself.

The password prompt is shown by GnuPG's *pinentry* component, which itself is started via *gpg-agent*. I don't really know where to start troubleshooting that on Windows – perhaps [a newer version](https://gpg4win.org/download.html) would work better. (Your GnuPG 2.0.22 was released in 2013.)

Newer versions, starting with GnuPG 2.1, support a "loopback pinentry" mode which can work without the *pinentry* component. If upgrading doesn't help on its own, try activating this option.

> that the sender needs to send me their public key

The sender's public key is useless for decryption and is only necessary for signature verification.

> Such as:
>
> ```
> pub 2048R/J561VE25 2015-09-23
> ```
>
> My thought it that the key files they sent me don't have the corresponding pub/sub info and therefore gpg can't validate because I only have one part of their keypair's information.

No. This bit of information is meant for *you*, the user – it summarizes the key's type, short (useless) ID, and expiry date. GnuPG can perfectly well extract it from the key itself, not that it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Well after much back & forth, I found the solution in two changes.

1. The gpg-agent.conf needed to have `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` added to it.
2. The script writer needed to add `--batch` to his command line.

Once that was done, gpg was able to get to the secret key and decrypt.

Thanks to grawity for replying. Your time is appreciated.

Comment: _The script writer needed to add --batch to his command line_ - what does that mean?